# Is there a simple code for fun addDetail in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

The following code can work well, but the code of `fun addDetail(...)` is too complex, is there a simple way  to do that ? Thanks!

BTW, in the `fun addDetail(...)`, `aMListDetail` maybe null, and `aMListDetail?.innerListDetail` maybe null.

```
data class MDetail (
        val _id: Long
)


class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) {

    data class MListDetail(val innerListDetail: MutableList<MDetail>)

    private var aMListDetail: MListDetail?

    var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext,"mySavedJson", "")

    init {
        aMListDetail= Gson().fromJson(mJson,MListDetail::class.java)
    }

    fun addDetail(aMDetail:MDetail){
        if (aMListDetail==null){
            aMListDetail=MListDetail(mutableListOf(aMDetail))
        }else{
            if (aMListDetail?.innerListDetail==null){
                aMListDetail=MListDetail(mutableListOf(aMDetail))
            }else {
                aMListDetail?.innerListDetail?.add(aMDetail)
            }
        }

        mJson = Gson().toJson(aMListDetail)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fun addDetail(aMDetail: MDetail) {
    if (aMListDetail?.innerListDetail == null) {
        aMListDetail = MListDetail(mutableListOf(aMDetail))
    } else {
        aMListDetail.innerListDetail.add(aMDetail)
    }

    mJson = Gson().toJson(aMListDetail)
}
```

Alternative:

```
fun addDetail(aMDetail: MDetail) {
    if (aMListDetail?.innerListDetail == null) {
        aMListDetail = MListDetail(mutableListOf())
    }

    aMListDetail.innerListDetail.add(aMDetail)
    mJson = Gson().toJson(aMListDetail)
}
```

You don't need null-safe `?.` operators in your `add()` call, since at that point you've already checked that `aMListDetail != null` and `innerListDetail != null`.

Comment: Thanks! But your code doesn't consider the case `aMListDetail?.innerListDetail==null`. In my code  I will do ` aMListDetail=MListDetail(mutableListOf(aMDetail))` when `aMListDetail?.innerListDetail==null`

Comment: @HelloCW that's because I think that Gson().fromJson() will either return a null `aMListDetail` or a non-null `aMListDetail.innerListDetail`, and will never return a null `aMListDetail.innerListDetail`. In other words, if `aMListDetail != null` then you know also that `aMListDetail.innerListDetail != null`. But if you want to program defensively, then by all means use `if (aMListDetail?.innerListDetail == null)` instead of just `if (aMListDetail == null)`.

Comment: BTW, I think I can the object aMListDetail is not null but aMListDetail.innerListDetail is null

Comment: A user maybe  store error data in "mySavedJson",  so   `var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext,"mySavedJson", "")` maybe cause aMListDetail.innerListDetail is null

Comment: `data class MDetail (...)` is complex class in my APP, I  skip some content

Answer (score 1):

> BTW, in the fun addDetail(...), aMListDetail maybe null,

Why not fix the problem at the source? You initialize it in the constructor, then tell Kotlin it *could* be set to null, but actually you never do this!

If you remove the unused nullability, the code simplifies to:

```
class DetailsHandler(mContext: Context = UIApp.instance) {

    data class MListDetail(val innerListDetail: MutableList<MDetail>)


    var mJson: String by PreferenceTool(mContext,"mySavedJson", "")
    // can even be val
    private var aMListDetail: MListDetail

    init {
        aMListDetail= Gson().fromJson(mJson,MListDetail::class.java)
    }

    fun addDetail(aMDetail:MDetail){
        aMListDetail.innerListDetail.add(aMDetail)

        mJson = Gson().toJson(aMListDetail)
    }

}
```

If your real code doesn't initialize it at the beginning, consider [`by lazy`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) or [`by notNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html).

> and aMListDetail?.innerListDetail maybe null.

Only is `aMListDetail` is null, which you should avoid as above.

Finally, if you really need `aMListDetail` to be `null` sometimes, you can write

```
aMListDetail?.let {
  it.innerListDetail.add(aMDetail)
}
```

(which does nothing if `aMListDetail` is `null`)

Answer (score 0):

```
fun addDetail(aMDetail:MDetail){
        if (aMListDetail?.innerListDetail==null){
            aMListDetail=MListDetail(mutableListOf(aMDetail))
        }else {
            aMListDetail?.innerListDetail?.add(aMDetail)
        }

    mJson = Gson().toJson(aMListDetail)
}
```

8-)